# Scope of Datas not updating after a $http AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope, ionic-framework

I can't understand why it does not update the $scope.user_free_status when I set a user free but when I unset the parameter it works perfectly. I need to reload page in one case and not the other... 
The datas fetched are stored in the localstorage.

Here is the code:

```
    .state('app', {
    url: "/app",
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: "templates/menu.html",
    controller: 'InitialCtrl',
    resolve: {
      theUserFreeStatus: function(DataService) {
        return DataService.getUserFreeStatus();
      }
    }
  })
```

Controller:

```
.controller('InitialCtrl', function($scope, $state, DataService ,FreeService, SharedService, theUserFreeStatus) {
// Showing set free but not unset or not
  if (FreeService.isSetFree()) {
    $scope.showSetFree    = false;
    $scope.showUnSetFree  = true;
  } else {
    $scope.showSetFree    = true;
    $scope.showUnSetFree  = true;
  }

  // Show the Free status set when arriving on page/app
  $scope.user_free_status = theUserFreeStatus;
  // Set user as Free
  $scope.setFree = function(activity, tags) {
    FreeService.setFree(activity, tags).success(function() {
      console.log($scope.user_free_status);
      $scope.user_free_status = DataService.getUserFreeStatus();
      console.log($scope.user_free_status);
      $scope.showSetFree    = false;
      $scope.showUnSetFree  = true;
      SharedService.goHome();
    })
  }  

  //// Free status unset
  $scope.unsetFree = function() {
    FreeService.unsetFree().success(function() {
      $scope.user_free_status = [];
      $scope.showSetFree    = true;
      $scope.showUnSetFree  = false;
      SharedService.goHome();
    });
  };
})
```

The services:

```
.factory('FreeService', function(WebService, $localstorage, $ionicPopup, DataService, $sanitize, CSRF_TOKEN) {
    var cacheFreeStatus = function(free_status) {
        $localstorage.setObject('user_free_status', free_status)
    };
    var uncacheFreeStatus = function() {
        $localstorage.unset('user_free_status')
    }
    return {
        setFree: function(activity, tags) {
            var status  = { SOME STUFF BLABLABLA };
            var setFree = WebService.post('setstatus/', sanitizeStatus(status));
            setFree.success(function(response) {
                console.log('available' + response.flash);
                cacheFreeStatus(response.status_response);
            })
            setFree.error(freeError)
            return setFree;
        },
        unsetFree: function() {
            var details  = {OTHER STUFF};
            var unsetFree = WebService.post('unsetstatus/', details);
            unsetFree.success(function(response) {
                console.log('unset ' + response.flash);
                uncacheFreeStatus(response.status_response);
            })
            unsetFree.error(freeError)
            return unsetFree;

        },
        isSetFree: function() {
            return $localstorage.get('user_free_status');
        }
    }
})
.service('DataService', function($q, $localstorage) {
  return {
    activities: $localstorage.getObject('activities'),
    getActivities: function() {
        return this.activities;
    },
    user_free_status: $localstorage.getObject('user_free_status'),
    getUserFreeStatus: function() {
        return this.user_free_status;
    }
  }
})
 * Local Storage Service
 ------------------------------------------------------*/
.factory('$localstorage', ['$window', function($window) {
  return {
    set: function(key, value) {
      $window.localStorage[key] = value;
    },
    unset: function(key) {
      localStorage.removeItem(key);
    },
    get: function(key, defaultValue) {
      return $window.localStorage[key] || defaultValue;
    },
    setObject: function(key, value) {
      $window.localStorage[key] = JSON.stringify(value);
    },
    getObject: function(key) {
      return JSON.parse($window.localStorage[key] || '{}');
    }
  }
}])
```

When setting the user's status, the console returns that the $http call worked but an empty array for the $scope variable I try to set. Once I reload the page I can see the updates displayed. If I unset the user's status, the $scope is properly updated without need to reload the page.
The Webservice is just the $http call.

What am I missing here to have the $scope.user_free_status updated correctly without having to reload the page??

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data service is injected as service but you have not appended the functions to this.rather you have returned it as part of literal like u do in factory

Comment: thanks for your input. What would you suggest doing? should I just write this.getUserFreeStatus

Comment: Yep..just use this.functionname and dont need to return any object.or if u wish to not change ur code u can change it to be a factory instead of service and it would be just fine

Comment: thanks. Is there a reason to want to use service over factory? I feel like the result is the same but factory is almost easier to write...

Comment: My personal view on this is..if u want to expose an api which mostly (not limited to)deals with talking to http CRUD services then its easier to use a service. When u seem to be in need of creating a thing (resembling a java bean) you would create it through a factory.this is entirely my opinion though.logically they both give u similar results

Comment: Thank you for your input :-) I've had a hard time understanding which one to use when since you can do the same with both.
I put up a codepen [link here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WbEoqo?editors=001) for the reworked service. I haven't been able to test it yet but does this look correct now?

Comment: Hmm...seen your code..But i see that u have saved the local storage to a variable and returning that when service method is called.Correct me if Im wrong but wouldnt you want the latest value from local storage each time u make a call for get status or activities

Comment: Meaning I should just code $localstorage.getObject('activities'); inside the function and get rid of the variable? I was wondering if one day I might need to work more those datas but what you are saying makes sense. The variable will be set at the begining and won't change when datas change in the localstorage....so that will never update. Am I correct? Tonight I'll integrate the code and mark your answer correct also :)

Comment: Yes.exactly.Since services are singletons,this local variable value would be same as the values of the local storage at the time of service creation.If you want to always fetch the latest values from storage ,you would put the localstorage getitem inside the exposed service methods.Hope things work out for you.Cheers!

Comment: ouch getting an error like that `Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: []`

Comment: Hmm I think you should have a look at your $watch code if you have any..u cud be manipulating scope inside the watch listener which is triggering further digests

Comment: Ummm... yes, I don't have any watch code or maybe Ionic has some. I ended up dumping the service and just use factory - went around the problem and now works! I won't be using any service soon :p